# How to test View in MVP+Dagger 2 in Android

Tags: android-espresso, android-testing, dagger-2, android-mvp

I develop a liitle application (example) and I want to train to write tests also. At that moment I have MyActivity class, that implement View interface, also I have Presenter interface. And I define all necessary methods in my MyActivity, but I still do not implement my Presenter interface.
There is code sample below:

```
public interface View {
   void showLocationInfo(String locationInfo);
}

public interface Presenter {
   void onButtonPressed();
}

public class MyActivity implement View {

    Button button;

    @Inject
    Presenter presenter;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        initDependencies();
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button)
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                    presenter.onButtonPressed();
               }
        });

    public void showLocationInfo(String locationInfo) {
       Log.d("MyLog", locationInfo);
    }

    private void initDependencies() {
       ... //init dependencies there by using Dagger 2  
    }
}
```

Question: How can I test MyActivity on this stage of development? 
I have a variant to create addition modules and component especially for testing View and create Presenter's implementation (mock) especially for testing. But where I should initialize this dagger component? In my Espresso test class?

Comment: Consider   https://github.com/konmik/testable-activity-example/blob/master/app/src/test/java/info/android15/testableactivity/MainActivityControllerTest.java

Comment: Is it possible to write a test that will run only MyActivity class using mocking Presenter class (and other mocking dependencies) to be tested handly?

Comment: While you can look into `Robolectric` for it to actually "emulate" android and create your activity for you, it might be better to keep your Activity as lean as possible by creating a testable controller for it as I linked above

Comment: Personally, I would forgo trying to Unit Test the View (Activity/Fragment), and instead make sure this is covered with UI (Espresso) instrumentation test. By keeping a passive view, and having you're domain logic housed in the presenter or another deeper layer, you can use plain JUnit for testing your Presenters. This will allow you to pass in mock objects for the view and test the methods get called as expected.